# Android Studio Subdirectories/packages suddenly cannot find R.java?

Tags: java, android

II updated AS to the latest stable build and all of my projects melted down. Only Java files in the main directory (com.company.app) can find R.java as intended. ALL of my subdirs can't find it. I did not have to import R.java before the update. I rebuilt my projects from scratch, restored backups, copy-paste to new projects from the backups, reinstalled AS, restarted PC, invalidated caches and restart, cleaned, literally every go to insta-fix-it solution that the internet always recommends and still I can't get this to work.

Can someone tell me how my subdirectories cant find R.java but other files in my main directory can? Is this a feature change in AS or something?  Are we now supposed to import R.java? There are no XML errors. My project built before I moved any subdirectory files back to my main package. The package name exactly matches the one in my manifest.

Edit 1: I can rebuild my project and make R.java. The main package files still see it without the import, but the subdirs can't find it.

Edit 2: I can move a file from my main package to a subdir and it still finds R.java. This appears to be a compiler glitch.

Edit 3: Importing R.java makes the errors go away so I guess that is a solution. I am leaving the question open because this makes no logical sense.

Comment: The `R` class is automatically generated at compile-time. Whenever I get this problem, it turns out I've incorrectly named a package. Make sure that the package name in the subdirectory matches that declared in the manifest. Also, you say "subdirectory", I imagine you meant to say "package", since Java files can be placed anywhere regardless of directory structure and important as if they were in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how App resources work.

When you build your android project, all of your resources in `/res` folder will be mapped automatically in generated `your.package.names.R` class.

Now you want to access the resources through the class. It's only make sense when you need to import the file when you use it in different package.

Comment: I have been making apps for 4 years now. I understand how they work. This requirement is brand new as of this week.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, even though the error wasn't being underlined in red there was an error in my strings.xml. Go to Values->strings.xml and check if you duplicated any strings.

Comment: No such luck. Thank you however. I will check everywhere for duplicates, but as the project built before my AS upgrade, I will be surprised if I see any.